# Command prompt quoting error

Tags: windows, command-line, shell, cmd.exe

If I have a Python program like this (substitute with any similar program):

```py
import sys
s = sys.argv[1]
print(s)
```

It just prints the argument provided. With Windows `cmd.exe`, if I want to
provide a literal redirect character `>`, I need to quote it:

```
C:\> python a.py ">"
>
```

and if I want to provide a literal double quote character, I need to use this
syntax:

```
C:\> python a.py """
"
```

My understanding is that with the second example, a literal double quote is only
recognized if it immediately follows a closing quote. So that example reads as
Open Quote, Close Quote, Literal Quote. However I noticed something strange,
this example:

```
C:\> python a.py """>
">
```

From my understanding, it seems the shell passed a literal redirect character in
error. If I understand the parsing, it should be Open Quote, Close Quote,
Literal Quote, Redirect (not literal). Is this in fact an error, or have I
misunderstood the parsing rules? Note I tested with Windows 10 and Windows 7.

Comment: each application in Windows parses the command parameters themselves, so the result may differ from an app to another. Most applications use the default Windows' libc implementation but cmd uses a different one, and python may in turn uses its own parsing rule. Use PowerShell instead which has a standard rule that makes passing special characters easier

Comment: What happens if you try: `python a.py \">\" ` ?? But, this seems work: `python a.py """>"""` see this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781011/how-to-pass-escape-characters-as-command-line-parameters-using-python)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, that the parsing rules as I understood them changed in 2008:

http://daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WINCRULES

Starting with C Runtime `msvcr90.dll`, command line argument parsing has been
improved. So instead of this:

```
C:\> python-2.5.4.amd64\python.exe a.py "a ""b"""" c"
a "b" c
```

Where the result is:

```
" open
a

" close
" literal
b
" open
" close
" literal
" open

c
" close
```

You can do this:

```
C:\> python-2.6.2.amd64\python.exe a.py "a ""b"" c"
a "b" c
```

Where the result is:

```
" open
a

" escape
" literal
b
" escape
" literal

c
" close
```

Finally, to address the orignal example:

```
" open
" escape
" literal
> literal
```

The correct command (in the context of sending one double quote and redirecting
the result) would be:

```
"""">
```